# Backticks in paragraphs

Tags: discussion, markdown

As you know, when you have html tags such as <html> in a post, you will need to put backticks around them, otherwise they wil come out invisible. However, I just found out by accident that when you have a HTML paragraph in a message, you can't use backticks inside!

For example, if I type

```
<p>This is a paragraph with some `<html>` inside.</p>
```

this comes out as

This is a paragraph with some `` inside.

Is this by design? If so, is this mentioned anywhere in the markdown documentation? Or is it simply a bug?

---

PS I know how to get around this: either use pure HTML, such as `<code>&lt;html&gt;</code>`, or use pure markdown, without `<p>` delimiters.
So I'm not asking what I should do here, I'm really asking if this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, this is by design.

---

From our [advanced Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html):

> Block-level HTML elements have a few restrictions:
>
> 1. They must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.
> 2. The begin and end tags of the outermost block element must not be indented.
> 3. Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.

Because `<p> text </p>` is HTML blocks, and `` `code` `` is Markdown syntax, so you can't use it in `<p> </p>` block.

Comment: Ah, OK. Your quote appears twice on that page even. I'll just have to learn to read.

Comment: @MrLister: Actually only once, it appears twice because the link is to that section. As the page said below: *The above section is quoted for convenience from the full editing help.* ;)